# How do i get a bounding polygon around points?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a table with thousands of addresses as points.

Is there a function in postgis that will allow me to get a bounding polygon around these points and return it as a polygon?

**update** I am looking for a more complex polygon than just a bounding rectangle

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It may be not 100% clear from your question what you mean as more *bounding polygon*. It may be understood as

- [minimum bounding rectangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_rectangle) (also known as MBR or envelope) for which you can use [ST_Envelope](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ST_Envelope.html), [ST_Box2D](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ST_Box2D.html) or [ST_Extent](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ST_Extent.html),
- as s a minimum geometry which encloses all points within given geometry, a [convex envelope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) and in this case you can use [ST_ConvexHull](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ST_ConvexHull.html) or even [ST_ExteriorRing](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ST_ExteriorRing.html) if your input would be a polygon,
- As Pimin pointed in the comments below, [ST_ConcaveHull](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_ConcaveHull.html) is another option worth to consider, available since PostGIS 2.0.0.

Comment: There is also ST_ConcaveHull in the most recent PostGIS, if you want a smaller polygon..

Answer (score 4):

[ST_Extent](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Extent.html) provides an aggregate function that returns a bounding box that bounds a set of geometries.

Comment: thanks. is there a way to get a more complex polygon than just a bounding box?